# C# How to place a window between desktop backgrounds and desktop icons

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-api-code-pack

I'm trying to make a program like a desktop calendar,finding problems when trying to place the window into desktop. I called windows API, it did put the window into desktop, and win+D won't hide the window, but still, the window remained above desktop icons, My code was like

```
var handle = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
            IntPtr hprog = FindWindowEx(
                FindWindowEx(
                    FindWindow("Progman", "Program Manager"),
                    IntPtr.Zero, "SHELLDLL_DefView", null
                ),
                IntPtr.Zero, "SysListView32", null
            );
            SetParent(handle, hprog);
```

Is there a way to put the window below those icons?

Comment: This is too broad.  The hack you're trying to use doesn't work past win7.  You might want to read [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/856020/Draw-Behind-Desktop-Icons-in-Windows-plus).

Comment: How often do you need to update your window? If not too often, why don't you take the current wallpaper, enrich it with the visuals of your window and set as a new wallpaper? Of course you would have to react on the wallpaper changes done not by your app.